# Debugging a PostgreSQL Remote Connection

Tags: postgresql, debugging, centos, remote-access, portforwarding

I'm having issues connecting to my PostgreSQL database from an online source.

PostgreSQL seems to be setup up fine it is running on it's default port 5432 and the postgresql.conf has the following line

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

And the pg_hba.conf has the following

```
host    dbname    usname    all    md5
```

I can connect to the PostgreSQL database from a different machine using the following credentials in pgadmin

```
Name              local
Host              192.xx.xx.xx
Port              5432
Maintenance DB    dbname
Username          usname
Password          psword
```

Using these I can connect perfectly it seems to work fine.

Then I forwarded the port 192.xx.xx.xx:5432 on the ADSL router and checked it using the public IP address 197.xx.xx.xx (visible to the internet IP)
http://www.canyouseeme.org/
Where I can see the port was forwarded ok.

However when I try to connect using

```
Name              online
Host              197.xx.xx.xx
Port              5432
Maintenance DB    dbname
Username          usname
Password          psword
```

I get the server doesn't listen error message

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "197.xx.xx.xx" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Why is this? Do I need to add an extra step to making it accept connections through port forwarding?

Comment: are you sure you don't have any firewall rules configured? in addition, if you use cloud provider like AWS you need to consider Security Groups as well

Comment: the firewall is disabled for testing, also I can connect to it from a remote computer on the network it's only when I try to access it through the forwarded port that it fails.

Comment: could you please update your question with sample command you are using?

Comment: I'm not using a command I'm using pgadmin (the postgresql gui interface)

Comment: x-post http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/240510/45708